# Context-free languages not closed under making them "extension-free"

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

For a language $L$, define:
$$
NE(L) = \{x \in L : x \text{ is not the proper prefix of any string in } L\}
$$

I'm trying to show context-free languages are *not* closed under this operation.
I've been struggling for a long time now trying to find a counterexample, that is, a language $L$ such that $L$ is context-free but $NE(L)$ is not context-free, and have come up with nothing. I'd appreciate ideas or hints about languages to look into.

Edit: For the vast majority of context-free languages, it seems that either $NE(L) = L$ or $NE(L) = \varnothing$. I'm having trouble even finding candidate languages.

Comment: Let $L = \{a^n\} \cup \{a^nb^n\}$, then $NE(L) = \{a^nb^n\}$. But $NE(L) \neq L \wedge NE(L) \neq \varnothing$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than the language $L\subseteq \Sigma^*$ consider the language $L' =L\$\$$, so concatenate every string by two copies of $\$$ where $\$$ is a new symbol not in $\Sigma$.

Let $x\in \Sigma^*$. 
String $x\$$ is not a proper prefix of $L'$ iff $x\$\$ \notin L'$ iff $x\notin L$.

That should start you going.

Comment: I've been staring at this for a while now, and I'm just not seeing it. Firstly, $x\$$ is not even in $L'$, so it certainly cannot be in $NE(L')$ (which is a subset of $L'$). To apply the criterion "is not a proper prefix of $L'$", we need to start with an $x \in L'$, otherwise we're not getting information about $NE(L')$. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: You are right. To get around this I think it suffices to consider $L' = L\$\$ \cup \Sigma^*\$$ instead.

Comment: Ah, clever. So essentially, we can use this construction to show that if $CFL$ were closed under $NE$, then it would have to be closed under complement to derive a contradiction. Alternatively, just pick a language whose complement fails to be CFL to get a counterexample. Thanks, I don't know *when* I would have thought of something like this...

Comment: $NE(L') = NE(L\$\$ \cup \Sigma^*\$) = L\$\$ \cup C(L)\$$.  But a union of a CFL and a non-CFL **can be** a CFL. This is a special case of course, since  it is a union of disjoint sets. So I think the alternative is easier: $L = \{a^mb^nc^p : m \neq n\} \cup \{a^mb^nc^p : n \neq p\}$.  Then $NE(L') = L\$\$ \cup \{a^mb^mc^m\}\$$. Now we are ready for the pumping lemma.

Comment: @AntonTrunov My suggestion for the "generic" case: The two parts of the language can be distinguished by their tails. So we can isolate $C(L)\$$ by intersecting with regular $\Sigma^*\$$.

Comment: @HendrikJan Do you mean $NE(L') \cap \Sigma^*\$ = C(L)\$$? But CFLs are not closed under intersection, so we can't prove by contradiction that $NE(L')$ is not a CFL. What am I missing?

Comment: @AntonTrunov Sorry, I should have been more precise. Context-free languages are closed under intersection with regular languages.

Comment: @HendrikJan Of course! Thank you! I misread your original comment about intersection.